# Extract apk and merge with updates, then install new apk

Tags: android

First of all, when you have app on your phone and this app has an update on play store, google returns only updated part of code instead of whole package (for example 3 mg instead of 8 mg that is size of whole package). I researched and figured out that on android side, google play extracts the local app and merge update file that downloaded from play store and generate new apk and then installs new apk along with update. Consider that play store doesn't have apk keystore to sign new apk, but apk gets installed successfully.
Now, I have an application that downloads updated apk from my server. Server detects changes between two apks and returns only changes done. Now, on android side I want to my running app to extract local apk and merge it with updates and generate new apk(like play store). Also it should sign new apk but it shouldn't put my keystore in user side file.
I recently in windows, unzipped an apk file and added some files from another apk to it. Both apks are signed. Placed that new apk in my phone. but android can't install the app and says "App cannot installed".
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Apps can not modify their APK. The apk file is only writable for the user `system` therefore it is impossible for regular apps on non-rooted devices to update or modify it's own or any other apk.

The only way would be to save to apk on the sdcard and then trigger side-loading of the app so that the user could chose to install it. But AFAIR that require the device to be activated for "Install apps from unknown sources" (which is disabled by default).

Signature: An APK signature consists of a text file containing the hashes of every file contained in and APK plus the signature of that text file.

Therefore if you have two APKs: One old APK and one new APK both signed correctly and you extract the changes (including the text file with the hashes and it's signature) between the old and the new one, and apply the extracted changes to the old apk the "updated old apk" will not be bitwise identical but it has the same content. Therefore the signature will be valid again.